# access VBA collection not displaying properly

Tags: ms-access, collections, vba

The idea is simple enough, populate and display a collection with different values. However it's only displaying the last value. I'm not sure whether the problem is in the populating sub or displaying part. Using access VBA

```
public sub populate(list as Collection)

dim i as integer
for i = 0 to 100
   dim e as new Numbers
   e.addition = i+i
   e.multiply = i*i
   list.add e
next
end sub
```

calling it:

```
    Dim test As Numbers
    Dim list as new Collection
    Call populate(list)
    For Each test In list

        Debug.Print test.addition & ", " & test.multiply      

    Next test
```

This only displays the LAST Numbers-Object in the list Collection 100 times.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `Dim e as new Numbers` does not create a new element each time, definitions are function wide., so you are just editing the same `Numbers e` each time. Moving the `Dim e as Numbers` outside the loop and using `Set e as new Numbers` inside the loop should do the trick:

(not tested)

```
public sub populate(list as Collection)

dim i as integer
dim e as Numbers
for i = 0 to 100
   Set e = new Numbers
   e.addition = i+i
   e.multiply = i*i
   list.add e
next
end sub
```